# Como pasar funcion de Javascript a Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Queria pasar esta funcion a jquery para colocar las animaciones a mi acordion, utilizo los parametros para seleccionar el elemento del acordion que quiero que se abra pero me da error, sino sleeciono el elemento del array entonces si sirve pero alo darle click para que se abra un elemento se abren todo, y yo quiero que se abra solo al que le de click, el codigo funciona con javascript nativo el problema es cuando lo quiero pasar a jquery, si no se puede diganme como se pueden usar las animaciones de jquery en javascript nativo lo estado buscando pero no encuentro nada

```js
 var lista = document.getElementsByClassName('lista');
 var icon = document.getElementsByClassName('fas');

 var clic = 1;

 function abrirCerrar(num){

  if(clic==1){
   lista[num].style.height = 'auto';
      lista[num].style.opacity = '1';
      icon[num].style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)';

   clic = 0;
  }else{
   lista[num].style.height = '0px';
   lista[num].style.opacity = '0';
   icon[num].style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';

   clic = 1;
  }
 }
```

```css
 *{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 }

  html{
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }

  body{
   background: #53CDE2;
  }

  a{
   text-decoration: none;
  }

  ul{
   list-style: none;
  }

        header{
         background: #005792;
         display: flex;
         flex-flow: row nowrap;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: space-between;
        }

  .logo{
   background: #fff;
  }

  .menu{
   padding: 20px;
  }

   .menu li{
    list-style: none;
          display: inline-flex;
         }

          .menu a{
           color: #EDF9FC;
           font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
           font-size: 20px;
           margin: 0px 20px;
           transition: 0.3s;
          }

          .menu a:hover{
           opacity: 0.1;
          }

       footer{
   background: #005792;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   padding: 20px 0px;
  }

   footer a{
    color: #EDF9FC;
    font-size: 15px;
   }

   footer a:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
   }

/*______________________Inicio________________________*/

  .texto-principal{
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-flow: column nowrap;
   background: url(imagenes/Pueblo_Paleta.png);
   background-position: center;
   background-attachment: contain;
   background-size: cover;
   height: 550px;
   text-align: center;
  }
   .texto-principal h1{
    color: #EDF9FC;
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
   }

   .texto-principal h3{
    color: #EDF9FC;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    opacity: 0.8;
   }

   .texto-principal .fas{
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 120px 0px 0px;
   }

  .romemu{
   width: 90%;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row nowrap;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   margin: 30px auto;
   background: rgba(209, 244, 250, 0.5);
   border-radius: 2px;
  }

   #roms{
    background: #D1F4FA;
    width: 600px;
    min-height: 450px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.8s;
   }

   #emuladores{
    background: #D1F4FA;
    width: 600px;
    min-height: 450px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.8s;
   }

    .titulor, .tituloe{
     width: 100%;
     background: #005792;
     color: #EDF9FC;
     text-align: center;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     padding: 10px 0;
     font-size: 22px;
    }

    .imgr{
     width: 65%;
     margin-top: 50px;
     padding: 20px;
     filter: drop-shadow(-12px 12px 5px #222);
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    .imgr:hover{
     filter: drop-shadow(-5px 5px 5px #222);
     opacity: 0.85;
    }

    .imge{
     width: 65%;
     margin-top: 50px;
     padding: 20px;
     filter: drop-shadow(12px 12px 5px #222);
     transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    .imge:hover{
     filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
     opacity: 0.85;
    }

     .rom, .emulador{
      width: 20%;
      margin: 60px 5px 5px 5px;
      padding: 5px;
      display: none;
     }

     .irom{
      width: 70%;
      position: relative;
      top: 25%;
      left: 15%;
      filter: drop-shadow(-13px 13px 5px #222);
      opacity: 0.8;
      transition: 0.5s;
     }

     .irom:hover{
      filter: drop-shadow(-5px 5px 5px #222);
      opacity: 1;
     }

     .iemu{
      width: 70%;
      position: relative;
      top: 25%;
      left: 15%;
      filter: drop-shadow(13px 13px 5px #222);
      opacity: 0.8;
      transition: 0.5s;
     }

     .iemu:hover{
      filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
      opacity: 1;
     }

/*____________________Roms_y_Emuladores____________________*/

        .list{
         background: rgba(209, 244, 250, 0.5);
         width: 90%;
   margin: 20px auto;
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   border-radius: 5px;
        }

         .separador{
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          margin: 20px;
          border-radius: 10px;
         }

          .list-label{
           cursor: pointer;
          }

          .separador h2{
           color: #EDF9FC;
           font-size: 35px;
           background: #005792;
           margin: 0;
           padding: 15px;
           border-radius: 5px;
           transition: 0.3s;
          }

          .separador h2:hover{
           opacity: 0.9;
          }

          .separador .fas{
           color: #EDF9FC;
           padding: 5px;
           transform: rotate(360deg);
           transition: 0.5s;
          }

          .list-selector{
           display: none;
          }

           .lista{
            background: #D1F4FA;
            list-style: none;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 10px;
                opacity: 0;
                height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-align: center;
            transition: 0.75s;
           }

            .list li{
             background: #005792;
             margin: 20px 10px;
             padding: 10px;
             border-radius: 5px;
            }

             .list a{
              color: #EDF9FC;
              font-size: 22px;
              transition: 0.4s;
             }

             .list a:hover{
              opacity: 0.3;
             }

/*__________________________Entradas____________________________*/

        .content{
         display: flex;
         flex-flow: row nowrap;
         align-items: center;
         justify-content: space-around;
         margin: 20px;
         padding: 20px;
        }

         .content_left{
          display: flex;
          flex-flow: column wrap;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: space-around;
          width: 75%;
          margin: 10px;
         }

          .content_left h1{
           position: relative;
           text-align: center;
           font-size: 40px;
           margin: 10px;
           color: #EDF9FC;
          }

          .content_left hr{
           color: #D1F4FA;
           width: 100%;
          }

          .content_left .product{
           display: flex;
           flex-flow: row nowrap;
           align-items: center;
           justify-content: center;
           margin: 10px;
          }

           .product img{
            width: 35%;
            margin: 10px;
           }

           .product table{
            margin: 10px;
               font-size: 22px;
            color: #D1F4FA;
           }

           .info{
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column nowrap;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-around;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 30px;
           }

             #dowrom, #dowemu{
              padding: 20px;
              margin: 17px;
                 border-radius: 5px;
             }

             #dowrom{
              background: #005792;
              color: #EDF9FC;
              font-size: 25px;
              transition: 0.3s;
             }

             #dowrom:hover{
              background: #D1F4FA;
              color: #005792;
             }

             #dowemu{
              background: #D1F4FA;
              color: #005792;
              font-size: 20px;
              transition: 0.3s;
             }

             #dowemu:hover{
              background: #005792;
              color: #D1F4FA;
             }

   .content_right{
    display: flex;
          flex-flow: column nowrap;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 20px;
   }

   .content h2{
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #D1F4FA;
   }

    .content .sub_product{
     height: 20%;
     margin: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     color: #005792;
    }

     .sub_product li{
      padding: 10px;
      background: #D1F4FA;
      margin: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      transition: 0.3s;
     }

     .sub_product li:hover{
      background: #005792;
     }

     .sub_product li:hover a{
      color: #D1F4FA;
     }

      .sub_product a{
       font-size: 17px;
       color: #005792;
       transition: 0.3s;
      }


  @media all and (max-width: 1000px){
   .romemu{
    flex-flow: column wrap;
   }
   .roms, .emuladores{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 15px auto;
   }
   .rom, .emulador{
    width: 45%;
   }
   .content{
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
   }
   .content_left{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 25px;
   }
   .content_right{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 25px;
   }
   .sub_product{
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
   }
   .sub_product li{
    display: inline-flex;
   }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>PokeRoms - Todas las Roms de Pokemon GB, GBC, GBA, N64, GC, NDS, WII, 3DS.</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Condensed:700" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="codigo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="logo">
   <a href=""></a>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="inicio.html">Inicio</a></li>
     <li><a href="roms.html">Roms</a></li>
     <li><a href="emuladores.html">Emuladores</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
 </header>
  <section class="list">
   <div class="separador" id="gb-roms">
    <label for="gb" class="list-label"><h2>GameBoy/GB Roms <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></h2></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" class="list-selector" id="gb" onclick="abrirCerrar(0)">
     <ul class="lista">
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GB) - Pokemon Azul</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GB) - Pokemon Amarrilla</strong></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="separador" id="gbc-roms">
    <label for="gbc" class="list-label"><h2>GameBoy Color/GBC Roms <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></h2></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" class="list-selector" id="gbc" onclick="abrirCerrar(1)">
     <ul class="lista">
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GBC) - Pokemon Cristal</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GBC) - Pokemon Plata</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GBC) - Pokemon Oro</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GBC) - Pokemon Pinball</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GBC) - Pokémon Puzzle Challenge</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GBC) - Pokémon Trading Card Game</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GBC) - Pokémon Trading Card Game 2</strong></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="separador" id="gba-roms" >
    <label for="gba" class="list-label"><h2>GameBoy Advance/GBA Roms <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></h2></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" class="list-selector" id="gba" onclick="abrirCerrar(2)">
     <ul class="lista">
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GBA) - Pokemon Rojo</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GBA) - Pokemon Verde</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GBA) - Pokemon Esmeralda</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GBA) - Pokemon Zafiro</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GBA) - Pokémon Rubi</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GBA) - Pokémon Equipo Misterioso: Equipo de Rescate Rojo</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GBA) - Pokémon Pinball: Rubi y Zafiro</strong></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="separador" id="n64-roms">
    <label for="n64" class="list-label"><h2>Nintendo 64/N64 Roms <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></h2></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" class="list-selector" id="n64" onclick="abrirCerrar(3)">
     <ul class="lista">
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(N64) - Pokemon Puzzle League</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(N64) - Pokemon Snap</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(N64) - Pokemon Stadium</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(N64) - Pokemon Stadium 2</strong></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="separador" id="gc-roms">
    <label for="gc" class="list-label"><h2>Nintendo GameCube/GC Roms <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></h2></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" class="list-selector" id="gc" onclick="abrirCerrar(4)">
     <ul class="lista">
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GC) - Pokemon Colosseum</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GC) - Pokemon Channel</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GC) - Pokemon XD: Tempestad Oscura</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(GC) - Pokemon Box: Rubi y Zafiro</strong></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="separador" id="nds-roms">
    <label for="nds" class="list-label"><h2>Nintendo DS/NDS Roms <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></h2></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" class="list-selector" id="nds" onclick="abrirCerrar(5)">
     <ul class="lista">
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokemon Diamante</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokemon Perla</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokemon Platino</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokemon Oro HeartGold</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokémon Plata SoulSilver</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokémon Mundo Misterioso: Equipo de Rescate Azul</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokémon Mundo Misterioso: Exploradores del Tiempo</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) Pokémon Mundo Misterioso: Exploradores de la Oscuridad</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokémon Mundo Misterioso: Exploradores del Cielo</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokémon Ranger</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokémon Sombras de Almia</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokémon Trazos de Luz</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokémon Dash</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokémon Link!</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokémon Negro</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokémon Blanco</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokémon Negro 2</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(NDS) - Pokémon Blanco 2</strong></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="separador" id="wii-roms">
    <label for="wii" class="list-label"><h2>Nintendo Wii/Wii Roms <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></h2></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" class="list-selector" id="wii" onclick="abrirCerrar(6)">
     <ul class="lista">
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(Wii) - PokePark Wii: La gran aventura de Pikachu</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(Wii) - PokePark 2: Un mundo de ilusiones</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(Wii) - Pokemon Battle Revolution</strong></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="separador" id="3ds-roms">
    <label for="3ds" class="list-label"><h2>Nintendo 3DS/3DS Roms <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></h2></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="list" class="list-selector" id="3ds" onclick="abrirCerrar(7)">
     <ul class="lista">
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(3DS) - Pokemon Omega Ruby</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(3DS) - Pokemon Omega Zafiro</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(3DS) - Pokemon X</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(3DS) - Pokemon Y</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(3DS) - Pokemon Sol</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(3DS) - Pokemon Luna</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(3DS) - Pokemon Ultra Sol</strong></a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href=""><strong>(3DS) - Pokemon Ultra Luna</strong></a>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </div>
  </section>
 <footer>
  <nav class="pie">
   <a href="">Desarrollado por Felix Lozada</a>
  </nav>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Esta seria la funcion si la paso a jquery

```js
 var lista = $('.lista');
 var icon = $('.fas');

 var clic = 1;

 $('.list-selector').click(function abrirCerrar(num){

  if(clic==1){
   lista[num].slideDown(1000);

   clic = 0;
  }else{
   lista[num].slideUp(1000);

   clic = 1;
  }
 })

var lista = $('.lista');
var icon = $('.fas');

var clic = 1;

$('.list-selector').click(function abrirCerrar(num){

 if(clic==1){
  lista[num].slideDown(1000);

  clic = 0;
 }else{
  lista[num].slideUp(1000);

  clic = 1;
 }
})
```

Comment: Qué error te da? Publicá tu código jQuery.

Comment: Ya puse el codigo de jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad lo que esta pasando es que ese argumento "num" que esperas en la funcion no existe.

Cuando agregas un evento de click en JQuery no es necesario declararlo en el HTML.

Esta parte del código debería quedar así:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="list" class="list-selector" id="gbc">
```

Luego si estas usando un checkbox lo mejor seria un onChange en vez de click. Por otro lado para validar si el elemento se encuentra chequeado puedes usar un  toggle.

Tu código podría quedar así:

```
var icon = $('.fas');

$('.list-selector').on("change", function (){
    $(this).next(".lista").slideToggle(1000);
})
```

Puedes ver tu codigo funcionando en este enlace: https://codepen.io/rtelenta/pen/xoqNdp

Comment: Gracias si me funciono, de casualidad no sabes hacer las animaciones de jquery pero con javascript nativo